# Using recursion to parse XML in iOS (ipad/iphone)

Tags: ios, xml, recursion

in an iPad application using XML I would like to understand if using recursion to parse an XML document will hog memory greatly. I ask this because the xml is around 6 levels deep and writing parsing logic for each node type would be tedious.

thanks in advance for your direction on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say it depends on the size of the stack. You can find more informations here [Threading Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html)

I cannot give you a clear answer since it depends on how big is your XML and how your code is written.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll read thread programming too, however, in general, say if I have to go through the entire XML file and print out the tags, would using recursion hog memory? its around 250KB file, if that helps in answering?

Comment: The part of the code who will be stuck in the stack will be the one responsible for the function call (related to objective-C message engine) and local variables. Since you are using objects, it would only be pointers.

I was not talking about how big in terms of bits, but how big in term of structural.

So I guess the best way to check this is by experiment, Do an infinite recursion who prints a number and see when it crashes you can allocate the same number of local variables that you'd use in your final algorithm.

Comment: To give you a clue. The objective-C messaging system is working like this :

The objective-c call : int result = [obj foo:@"hello"];
Is in reality : int result = ((int (*)(id, SEL, NSString *))objc_msgSend)(obj, @selector(foo:), @"hello");

Comment: I understand. Since it would be pointers being retained on the stack due to recursive calls, the recursive should theoretically hog memory after a somewhat long time. So I should go ahead and try it.. :-) thanks so much

Comment: No problem :) It should work if you don't have too much sub levels. But you should implement recursive limit is case of you'll receive xMb xml. Preventing your app to crash if it's doing recursion more than a certain size. Just pass to your method an NSUInteger called maxDepth and every time you'll do maxDepth-- in the method. You'll be then able to throw an exception and print a nice error information. Instead of crashing which is more frustrating for the user.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to NOT use NSXMLParser (the internal one).

Look here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project.

I recommend you to use GDataXML (part of the google iOS Toolkit). It's very fast, low mem footprint and reliable.
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/XMLSupport/

You can do than some XPath's to access your data in the xml:

```
GDataXMLDocument *xmlDocument = [[GDataXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
GDataXMLElement *rootElement = [xmlDocument rootElement];

NSError *xPathError;
NSArray *objects = [rootElement nodesForXPath:@"//NodeA/NodeB" error:&xPathError];
```

If you are new to XPath: check http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/xpath.html

Greetings

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I've looked at these libraries. My problem is that I have to parse and process the whole XML so it's a sequential read of the file from start to finish, and in each of the above libraries, I will have to code several functions to extract data from each node into custom objects. I was trying to see if I can make my life easier if i use say GDataXML with recursively trying to access each node. Pls let me know if you can give me direction in this.

Comment: Okay. Than you can try to parse with NSXMLParser (SAX). If you like to have more speed and less mem footprint, than use libxml's c interface: http://www.jamesh.id.au/articles/libxml-sax/libxml-sax.html